# Extracting each digit in an int

Tags: java

So I'm in a process of writing a small encrypter program. I start by asking the user to enter a 4 digit number (>= 1000 and <= 9999). I'd like to extract each digit from the number entered by the user, and store them in a variable.

My assignment gives me hint which doesn't help me much (Hint: integer division and the modulus might be useful here).

Comment: You could also convert the integer to a String, split the String into separate digits, then convert each digit to an integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "hint" is actually a nearly direct explanation of how to do what you need to do: dividing in integers by ten gets rid of the last digit, while obtaining modulo ten gives you the last digit:

```
int x = 12345;
int lastDigit = x % 10;       // This is 5
int remainingNumber = x / 10; // This is 1234
```

Do this in a loop until the remaining number is zero. This gives you digits of the number in reverse.

Comment: So the last digit will be stored in "lastDigit" and the remainder of the digits are stored in "remainingNumber". And so the next step would be to loop it again until no more digits are left (or remainder of zero). Unless I'm mistaking, that would change the numbers assigned in the variable though.

Comment: This is what the question asks me to do:                                                            Extract each digit and save them into four int variables. (Hint: integer division and the modulus might be useful here).
e) Encrypts each digit by replacing it with the (sum of that digit plus 7) modulo 10. Swap the 1st digit with the 3rd and the 2nd digit with the 4th.

Comment: @JKawa You don't need a loop then. You know how to take the last digit, and also how to drop the last digit. Make four variables `digit0`, `digit1`, `digit2` and `digit3`, assign them one by one, and modify a separate variable, say, `y`, instead of modifying `x`.

Comment: Perfect, the first part is done.. i can't seem to figure out the next step though, spent quite an amount of time with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer.toString(int)` and then address each digit by index.

```
int x = 1234;
char[] s = Integer.toString(x).toCharArray();
System.out.println(s[0]);
System.out.println(s[1]);
System.out.println(s[2]);
System.out.println(s[3]);
```

If you don't want to convert your string to an array you can use the `.charAt(int n)` method on the string.

```
int x = 1234;
String s = Integer.toString(x);
System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Probably not what the homework wants, but certainly not wrong.

Comment: I was a bit hasty, and forgot that you cannot index strings in java...